# What should we do about optimizing for iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7

Today, Apple announced to iOS7 developers:

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be
>   optimized for iOS 7. Learn more about preparing your apps by reviewing
>   the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

http://techcrunch.com/2013/12/17/apple-requiring-all-app-submissions-to-be-optimized-for-ios-7-by-feb-1st/

What should we do about that? Use iOSSDK7.0 or later? Use Xcode5.0 or later?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should read the iOS Human Interface Guidelines..

Comment: `Use Xcode5.0 or later?` doesn't the announcement exactly say that?!

Comment: Like the announcement says, You should build this on XCode 5.0 or later. But its not necessary to change UI and appearance for iOS7

Comment: You will probably also be required to have all the appropriate icon sizes for ios 7. Just a guess though.

Comment: This is an excellent question actually. Apple's statement is *incredibly* vague as to what 'optimized' means and to what extent you must adhere to the 'HIG'

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing for iOS 7 is not an entirely technical task. Yes, you should be using the latest SDKs and Xcode, but what this really means is that you should have read and following the **iOS7 UI Transitions Guide**, [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/) and the various other style guides within the Apple Developer Center.

Comment: No, just following the iOS7 UI Transitions Guide is **NOT** enough. Apple just sent a new email that clarifies this. **"Make sure your apps work seamlessly with the innovative technologies in iOS 7. Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK."**

Comment: I understand that Apple would like everyone to use Helvetica Thin, but is there any statement from Apple that apps must look like native iOS7 apps? Given how many apps tend to not look anything like native app UIs, I find this will be hard for Apple to police.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are :

- Use **XCode 5.0** or later
- Use **iOSSDK7.0** or later
- **Deference**. The UI helps users understand and interact with the content, but never competes with it.
- **Clarity**. Text is legible at every size, icons are precise and lucid, adornments are subtle and appropriate, and a sharpened focus on functionality motivates the design.
- **Depth.** Visual layers and realistic motion impart vitality and heighten users’ delight and understanding.
- **Defer to Content** - Take advantage of the whole screen, Reconsider visual indicators of physicality and realism, Let translucent UI elements hint at the content behind them,
- **Provide Clarity** - Use plenty of negative space, Let color simplify the UI, Ensure legibility by using the system fonts, Embrace borderless buttons
- **Use Depth to Communicate**
- Just look at original Apple apps, your must follow that style

Addition info at links

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Anatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH24-SW1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html

Comment: so...the requirements are for a large part, subjective? I'm actually all for HIGs but this announcement from Apple is vague, at best. Given how many apps ignore Apple's HIGs altogether, I don't see how Apple is going to police this.